# Python: How to delete numbers in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, startswith, ends-with

Python learner here. So I have a wordlist.txt file, one word on each line. I want to filter out specific words starting and ending  with specific letters. But in my wordlist.txt, words are listed with their occurrence numbers.

For example:

```
food 312
freak 36
cucumber 1
```

Here is my code

```
wordList = open("full.txt","r", encoding="utf-8")
word = wordList.read().splitlines()

for i in word:
    if i.startswith("h") and i.endswith("e"):
        print(i)
```

But since each item in the list has numbers at the end I can't filter correct words. I could not figure out how to omit those numbers.

Comment: You can use python's split() function which will split your line by "space" charachter.

Comment: Split each word by whitespace, into the actual word and the number, then ignore the number: `for word in words: actual, *_ = word.split()` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting the line using space as the delimiter and use the first value `[0]` which is the word in your case

```
for i in word:
    if i.split(" ")[0].startswith("h") and i.split(" ")[0].endswith("e"):
        print(i.split(" ")[0])
```

Or you can just peform the split once as

```
for i in word:
    w = i.split(" ")[0]
    if w.startswith("h") and w.endswith("e"):
        print(w)
```

EDIT: Based on the comment below, you may want to use no argument or None to split in case there happen to be two spaces or a tab as a field delimiter.

```
w = i.split()[0]
```

Comment: You may want to use no argument or None to split, in case there happen to be two spaces or a tab as a field delimiter.

Comment: @00 : Added your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: This solution filters the words correctly but numbers are still there.

Comment: @aydgn Then `print(w)` instead of `print(i)`…

Comment: @aydgn : yes, print (w)

Comment: That solved my problem. I don't understand what [0] does. I'm just a beginner so can you send my any article about it?

Thanks Sheldore and @Melebius. :)

Comment: @aydgn : when you split, it results in 2 strings, the first one is the word and the second one is the number. The 0 and 1 are the indices for these two strings. To access first, you use `[0]` index and to access the second, you use `[1]`index. Read [this document](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str = "This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes 12345"
str = re.sub(" \d+", "", str)
```

The str will be =
"This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes"

Comment: For a beginner, you should include the necessary statement `import re` in your answer.